# view pager fire click event of second fragment while showing first one android

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-support-library

I have a problem using view pager in android

I have a button with click event in the second fragment, but this event is fired when I press on the same position of button but on the first event

please help if you can

Comment: cannot help you without code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the same problem, and I don't find any solution too. I'm working on a gallery using viewpager and TouchImageView, and after some swipe, the pinch zoom doesn't work because the touch event is captured by the page which is not displaying, not the current page, very strange. And also I found that if I don't use DepthPagerTransformer everything is just fine.

Comment: After some research, I found out that we can simply solve this problem if you're in the same case. in setPrimaryItem of ViewPager, bring the current view to front by view.bringToFront() so the current page will receive the event.

Comment: It works fine with me also when i didn't use DepthPagerTransformer